# while select function in option minLength :3 is not working in autocomplate jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

While select function in option `minLength :3`  is not working in autocomplate jquery.

While loading page I have made call of `initAutoComplete` function it will bind `autocomplete` to given html text box filed.
    If I have set minlength to 1 or 0 it working fine but when I will set it to more then 1 i.e `minLength : 2` or `minLength : 3`, it is not working and not populate auto suggetion option.

```
$(function() {
initAutoComplete();
}    

/* Auto complete function */
function initAutoComplete(){
var firstNameField = $("#txt_websend_recipientFirstName");
    firstNameField.autocomplete({
        minLength: 3,
        select: function( event, ui ) {         
            var firstName = ui.item.firstName;
            var lastName = ui.item.lastName;
            var company = ui.item.company;
            var faxNumber = ui.item.fax;
            var country = ui.item.country;

            Websend.populateContactInfo(firstName, lastName, company, faxNumber, country);
            return false;
        }
    }).data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function(ul, item){
        return $("<li></li>")
        .data("item.autocomplete", item)
        .append("<a>" + item.label + "</a>")
        .appendTo(ul);
    };
firstNameField.data("autocomplete")._normalize = function(items){
        // assume all items have the right format when the first item is complete
        $.each(items, function(index, item){
            item.value = item.firstName;
            item.label = item.firstName;    
        });
        return items;
    }
    //update listener
    $(document).bind("addressbook.loaded", function(event,data){
        updateSource(data.data);
    }); 
}
```

It is bind source of option which given in addressbook contact.

```
function updateSource(data){
    var firstNameField = $("#txt_websend_recipientFirstName");
    firstNameField.autocomplete("option", "source", data);
}
```

Comment: Need a solutioon for minLengh setting in autocomplete jquery not able to get proper solution with this code. i have tried
firstNameField .autocomplete({
         minLength: 3,
         source: data
     });
In updateDataSource method please look into this